# How to Filter a Pandas Dataframe Column of Lists

Tags: python, pandas

Goal: To filter rows based on the values of column of lists.

Given:

| index | pos_order |
| --- | --- |
| 3192304 | `['VB', 'DT', 'NN', 'NN', 'NN', 'NN']` |
| 1579035 | `['VB', 'PRP', 'VBP', 'NN', 'RB', 'IN', 'NNS', 'NN']` |
| 763020 | `['VB', 'VBP', 'PRP', 'JJ', 'IN', 'NN']` |
| 1289986 | `['VB', 'NN', 'IN', 'CD', 'CD']` |
| 69194 | `['VB', 'DT', 'JJ', 'NN']` |
| 3068116 | `['VB', 'JJ', 'IN', 'NN', 'NN']` |
| 1506722 | `['VB', 'NN', 'NNS', 'NNP']` |
| 3438101 | `['VB', 'VB', 'IN', 'DT', 'NNS', 'NNS', 'CC', 'NN', 'NN']` |
| 1376463 | `['VB', 'DT', 'NN', 'NN']` |
| 1903231 | `['VB', 'DT', 'PRP', 'VBP', 'JJ', 'IN', 'NNP', 'NNP']` |

I'd like to find a way to query this table to fetch rows where a given pattern is present. For example, if the pattern is `['IN', 'NN']`, I should get rows 763020 and 3068116, but **not** row 3438101. So to be clear, *the order of the list elements also matters*.

I tried going about it, this way:

```
def target_phrase(pattern_tested, pattern_to_match):
    if ''.join(map(str, pattern_to_match)) in ''.join(map(str, pattern_tested)):
        print (pattern_tested)
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I can run this code using lists outside of pandas, but when I try using something like:

```
target_phrase(df.loc[5]['pos_order'], ['IN', 'NN'])
```

the code fails.

Any clue?

Comment: What is the actual data type of the data in the column? More precisely, what gives `type(df.iloc[0]['pos_order'])`

Comment: in: type(df.iloc[0]['pos_order'])

out: str

Answer (score 2):

First, let me provide a simplified view of `target_phrase`:

```py
def target_phrase(pattern_tested, pattern_to_match):
    return ''.join(map(str, pattern_to_match)) in ''.join(map(str, pattern_tested))
```

Why the code does not work? Because `target_phrase` expects the first argument to be a list, not a pandas dataframe. The correct syntaxis is as follows:

```py
df['pattern_matched'] = df.apply(lambda x: target_phrase(x['pos_order'], 
                                                         ['IN', 'NN']), axis=1)
```

This function applies `target_phrase` row-wise.

Comment: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1peWGZl01SAdAKHWaO9zV9F3EQWtZiwlQ/view?usp=sharing] Here is a sample of the document. 

When I run this document pass the code you suggest, I get "False" for all rows.

So it's working yet, but I do think you're right about the issue being how the information is passed through. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out it was a combination of things, things that Kate and Serge together led me to figure out.

As I had everything, the data types being compared were not similar. I was comparing a string to a list. I had to add code to convert that string that looked like a list to a list--Serge's contribution. Once that was done, I was able to successfully run lambda thanks to Kate.